# Why copy paste from OSx to iOS is not working

Tags: macos, ios, copy-paste, ventura

If I copy some text in OSx then I couldn't paste in my iOS device.

I have enabled hand off in both iOS and Mac

I have logged in using the same apple ID

I have turned Wifi and blue tooth on in both the devices

Both the devices are connected to same wifi.

> Mac: Mac book pro 16 inch 2021 , Ventura 13.5.1
>
> iOS: iPhone 13 pro , iOS 16.6

[image]

[image]

I'm able to do air drop

Comment: Handoff needs to be enabled.

Comment: How do you copy *what exactly* from a Mac to an iOS device? If there is something on the iPhone/iPad that can work with the file (EG photos.app for pics, Music.app for music, etc...) then Handoff should work fine. But **the iPhone is not a thumb drive.** So if you are just trying to store an assortment of files so they can be easily transported to another device then the iPhone/iPad is not a good choice.

Comment: Mostly I intend to copy the text

Comment: Have you got WiFi and Bluetooth enabled on both devices?

Comment: Wifi Yes but not the bluetooth

Comment: @jksoegaard - I have enabled bluetooth and wifi .. but still not working

Comment: Are you signed into the same AppleID?

Comment: @Allan - Yes , I even signed out and signed in back. just to make sure everything is ok